# How to put HashMap<K, V> elements inside a TreeMap<V, K> with duplicate keys?

Tags: java, collections, maps

I have a Hashmap with duplicate keys, want to assign the elements in a Treemap format. I'm trying out this below code but this is not inserting duplicate keys in the Treemap.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> totalCustomersByPin = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
TreeMap<Integer,Integer> totalDeliveriesToPin = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer();
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = totalCustomersByPin.entrySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> pair = iterator.next();     
    totalDeliveriesToPin.put(pair.getValue(), pair.getKey());
}       
System.out.println("Top pincodes:" + totalDeliveriesToPin);
```

Comment: "duplicate keys"? How is that possible? What do you mean by "duplicate keys"?

Comment: You can't. TreeMaps don't support duplicate keys, since they are `Map`s. You'd need to use something like Guava's [`TreeMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html).

Comment: @Tunaki: means for the hashmap a particular pincode is key and the no of times a parcel has been delivered to that pincode is value. now i want the no to be the key and the pincode to be the value in Treemap. but for different pincodes there could be a chance that parcel delivered same n times.

Comment: @Andy: seems a good option. I'll give it a try..thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java native maps don't support this. You can use [MultiValuedMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) from apache commons.

However I assume you want to sort it by numbers of values for the key. You'll need to implement Comparator for this, sorting by the number of values in the collection.  TreeMap will not help here.

Answer (score 0):

[TreeMap#public V put(K key, V value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) according to it's docs

**Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.**

To do what you are looking for you need a Multimap - which is essentially a Map to a List.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> multiMap;
```

To add an object get the list for that key, if it is null add a list then add your value to the list, otherwise just add your value to the existing list.